# What is a ferroelectric metal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals

I was reading online about ferroelectricity, and came upon the topic of ferroelectricity in metals. The main cited paper is the one below by Anderson and Blount in the 1960's

- Symmetry Considerations on Martensitic Transformations: "Ferroelectric" Metals? P. W. Anderson and E. I. Blount. [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **14**, 217 (1965)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.14.217).

What I am struggling to understand is the meaning of a metallic ferrolectric. Obviously metals completely screen out the dipoles, so no real ferroelectric moment can form. It seems the paper is just discussing a structural transition that breaks inversion symmetry (e.g. some atom moves in a special polar axis direction). But in this case, wouldn't any metal without inversion symmetry qualify as a "ferroelectric metal"?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article [Ferroelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity) and some of the references given therein?

Comment: @Farcher, yes I have.  The issue of metallic ferroelectricity is not covered there.

Comment: @Farcher I've added a link without the paywall

Comment: This recent review may be of interest to you: https://doi.org/10.35848/1347-4065/ab8bbf

Comment: See https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-018-0336-3 as well